# Create teaser from HTML content

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'd like to create a **teaser** (preview) of my HTML content (article) using already existing data (imported).

Current table schema:

```
Id | Text                                                             | Teaser
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1 | <p>Ready</p><p>when</p><p>you are!</p><p>We will start from...</p> | NULL
```

I'd like to take first 3 paragraph and recieve next output:

```
Id | Teaser
------------------------------------------
1 | <p>Ready</p><p>when</p><p>you are!</p>
```

I'm pretty sure i could do that using C# (external app or sql injected function) but are there any simple way to achieve that using ANSI sql/t-sql?

It could be great if `PATINDEX` could contain `startFrom` index but it does not, or i could insert special separator using `STUFF` right afther `n` element.

May be there is a split function that use regular expression (for example `<p>%</p>`) and skip take result elements?

Comment: What if the HTML is `<p> .....insert thousands of chars.... </p>`? Or if it's invalid HTML?

Comment: @DavidG that's rare in my case and i could control it next using LEN(Teaser) > MaxTeaserLength

Comment: Wrap my example in another `div` and your `LEN` test breaks.

Comment: @DavidG But mb you are right and i have to take first MaxTeaserLength characters, revert, search first point/space and replace it with </p> and finally revert

Comment: @DavidG I've already clean up all of my article content and there are not  anything than <p>*</p>

Comment: What I was trying (perhaps badly!) to suggest, was that maybe using SQL isn't the best way to achieve what you want. Personally, if possible I would do this in C# or let the user make a teasers.

Comment: @DavidG Yeah, thank you for your suggestions, but i'd like to optimize amount of data that i fetch from database (select teaser and do not select text) and in this case, i think, i have to store it

Comment: I agree it may be a good idea to store it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Declare @YourTable table (Id int,Text nvarchar(max), Teaser nvarchar(500))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(1,'<p>Ready</p><p>when</p><p>you are!</p><p>We will start from...</p>',NULL),
(2,N'<p>будь здоров</p><p>Ready</p><p>when</p><p>you are!</p><p>We will start from...</p>',NULL)

Update @YourTable Set Teaser = left(Text,B.RetPos+3)
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply (
                Select RetPos 
                 From  (
                        Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order by N)
                              ,RetPos = N
                        From  (Select N=Row_Number() over (Order by (Select null)) From master..spt_values ) N
                        Where  N <= Len(A.Text) and substring(A.Text,N,len('</p>')) = '</p>'
                       ) S
                 Where RetSeq=3
             ) B



Select ID,Teaser from @YourTable
```

Returns

```
ID  Teaser
1   <p>Ready</p><p>when</p><p>you are!</p>
2   <p>будь здоров</p><p>Ready</p><p>when</p>
```

Comment: John Cappelletti, works great with eng but there are `???` result with cyrillic characters (for example <p>будь здоров</p> -> <p>???</p>)

Comment: I've changed like this `(@String nvarchar(max),@Delimiter nvarchar(25))` but i'm afraid it didn't help

Comment: @FSou1 Huh.. let me get back to you

Comment: @FSou1 We still use the Parse to calculate the LEN() of the teaser, then we apply the left(Text,n) to the teaser

Comment: @FSou1 See updated approach.  No need for the UDF, we can use a CROSS APPLY to find the nPos